# Old ansible playbook executes everytime

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have written an ansible(2.0) playbook for installing sonarqube on a box. I changed a detail in the sonarqube role as I was facing an issue. It seems like ansible doesn't detect the change as I change my playbook. I have tried commenting/ deleting the tasks. I have used --flush-cache, but it didn't work.

Any help will be appreciated. Please let me know if any other detail is required from my side.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Very weird issue. The ansible playbook was checked-in my git repository.

On the go modifications of the code was not working. I had to commit the changes and pull the changes to make it work. Looks like the caching was from git side.